# Laravel 8 - how to fetch data from the database using an object as a "where" condition?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

im new in laravel programming and im trying to do something with laravel Eloquent.

So i have 3 tables, dev, dev_project(many to many) and project.

- i need to see in which projects the dev is part of, using the dev_project table, and get the corresponding id from projects.
- after that i need to go to the table project, and use the id that I got from the many-to-many table to get the corresponding name of the projects in which that same dev is part of.

First im fetching data from my DB into a variable

```
$devproject = DB::table('dev_project')->where('id_dev', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
```

And then Im trying to get the data from the project table where the id is the same from the one that i fetched before

```
return Project::where('id', $dev_project->id_project);
```

The problem here is that the variable dev_project is an object, and i cant use a foreach and store the data that i want to return inside an array.

So how can I get all the data that i want in the same object.

I appreciate any help, Thank you.

Comment: Hint: use `eloquent` and `relationship`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra please elaborate.

Comment: You can refer https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many . The example they have given is analogically the same as your tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here, `$devproject` is  a Collection, not a single row. `$dev_project->id_project` is not a valid property.

- If you want the first result's `id_project`, then the syntax is `$devproject->first()->id_project`.
- If you want a Collection of each of `$devproject` 's `id_project`, then the syntax should be `$devproject->pluck('id_project')`.

With that in mind, your query should either be

```php
return Project::where('id', $dev_project->first()->id_project);
```

or

```php
return Project::whereIn('id', $dev_project->pluck('id_project'));
```

---

As harish durga suggests, a relationship would save you the trouble of writin these queries.

```php
# Dev Model

public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 'dev_project', 'id_project', 'id_dev');
}
```

```php
# Project Model

public function devs()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Dev::class, 'dev_project', 'id_dev', 'id_project');
}
```

```php
# Get all devs with associated projects:
$devs = Dev::with('projects')->get();

foreach ($devs as $dev) {
    echo $dev->...
    foreach ($dev->projects as $project) {
        echo $project->...
    }
}
```

Comment: where do i put this code? 

`$devs = Dev::with('projects')->get();
foreach ($devs as $dev) {
    echo $dev->...
    foreach ($dev->projects as $project) {
        echo $project->...
    }
}
`

Comment: It's an example

Comment: i tried to use queries but when i use this `return Project::whereIn('id', $devproject->pluck('id_project'));` i get this error `Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response::setContent() must be of the type string or null, object given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\check_listsv2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Response.php on line 72`

Comment: `return json_encode(Project::......);`